# Why do you have to use an array for dependency injection in AngularJS with controllers, but not for other functions and methods?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, controller, minify

In AngularJS, we use an array to pass the services as arguments to the controller function so that they keep their functionality after minification. for example:

```
myApp.controller('mycontroller', [$scope, $log, function($scope, $log){

  $scope.name = 'Jimmy';

  $log($scope.name);

}]);
```

But when you inject a dependency to the .config method, you don't have to use an array. For example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){

     $routeProvider

     .when('/', {

           templateURL: 'pages/main.html',
           controller: 'myController'
     })
});
```

I'm having a hard time understanding dependency injection in AngularJS. I thought I understood it but I guess I don't. Wouldn't the variable name $routeProvider be minified and lose it's functionality as a service, the same as when you use dependency injection (without an array) with a controller?

Comment: Why do you think `config` is exempt from the array-based DI convention? The official documentation even has an example snippet where they clearly use the dependencies array—https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module#module

Comment: Oh. Well I saw it when I was watching a video series as part of a course to supplement the docs because I found them too complicated. Thanks for pointing this out.